# Increment a badge value when button clicked in RecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, mysql, notifications, counter, badge

I am working on an app which allows users to increment the value of a notification badge by clicking on the "OK" button of an AlertDialog. This value will be stored in a MySQL database.

The AlertDialog is set in a RecyclerAdapter, the notification Badge is set in the Main activity, and I use a Utils class for the Badge count.

What is the best way to implement that, please ?

**UPDATE**

**Counter class**

```
public interface Counter {
public void setCounter(int count);}
```

**Adapter class** :

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

Context c;
ArrayList<criteria> critere;
private Counter counter;

public RecyclerAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<criteria> critere, Counter counter) {
    this.c = c;
    this.critere = critere;
    this.counter = counter;
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    Integer count;
    TextView criteria, update;
    ImageButton btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4;
    Boolean click1, click2, click3, click4;
    ImageView image;
    RelativeLayout layout;
    LinearLayout ranked;
    ImageView check;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    public ClipData.Item currentItem;
    public View view;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;

        btn1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn4);

        layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.check_view);
        ranked = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank_layout);
        check = itemView.findViewById(R.id.check_image);

        criteria = itemView.findViewById(R.id.criteria_text);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.criteria_pic);

    }

}

@Override
public RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.recycler_model,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final criteria crit = critere.get(position);

    final String name = crit.getName();

    //BIND
    holder.criteria.setText(name);
    holder.layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    PicassoClient.downloadImage(c,crit.getImageurl(),holder.image);

    holder.btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(c);
                View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_rank, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);

                dialog.setView(dialogView);
                dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.btn_press_rank1);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setTitle(R.string.crit1);
                dialog.setMessage("The " + name + " was very unsatisfiying");
                final EditText userInput = (EditText) dialogView
                        .findViewById(R.id.comment_field);

                dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //checked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.check.bringToFront();
                        holder.ranked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        counter.setCounter(1);

                    }
                })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.annuler, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                //checked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                holder.layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                holder.ranked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        });

                final AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
                alert.show();

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return critere.size();
}}
```

**MainActivity class** :

```
public class RankActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String jsonURL="xx/criteria.php";
RecyclerView rv;
private int mNotificationsCount = 0;
private Counter counter;
TextView notif;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rank);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    notif = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.badge_notification_1);

    new RankActivity.FetchCountTask().execute();

    counter = new Counter() {
        @Override
        public void setCounter(int count) {
            Log.e("Ser_Counter", "" + count);
            notif.setText(count + "");
            Toast.makeText(RankActivity.this, "Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(RankActivity.this, 2));

    new Downloader_recycler(RankActivity.this,jsonURL, rv, counter).execute();
}

public void OnSave(MenuItem item){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_user, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications);
    MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.notification_update);
    //notificationCount = (RelativeLayout) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    //LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) item.getIcon();
    //Utils.setBadgeCount(this, icon, mNotificationsCount);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_notifications) {
        // TODO: display unread notifications.
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void updateNotificationsBadge(int count) {
    mNotificationsCount = count;
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

class FetchCountTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Integer count) {
        updateNotificationsBadge(count);
    }
}}
```

Comment: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43015908/android-change-cart-menu-badge-counter-from-recycler-adapter) it might be helpful for you!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**This is how I fixed this** (without the interface)

In the main activity, I changed the way I was implementing the badge and added two methods :

```
 public void update() {
    if (count>=5)
    {count = count +1;}
    display(count);
}
```

and

```
private void display(int count) {
    notif = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.badge_notification_1);
    notif.setText(""+ count);
}
```

**This is the new Main Activity class :**

```
public class RankActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String jsonURL="http://xx/load_criteria.php";
RecyclerView rv;
TextView notif;
int count = 5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rank);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(RankActivity.this, 2));

    new Downloader_recycler(RankActivity.this,jsonURL, rv).execute();
}

public void OnSave(MenuItem item){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_user, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications);
    MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.notification_update);
    //notificationCount = (RelativeLayout) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    //LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) item.getIcon();
    //Utils.setBadgeCount(this, icon, mNotificationsCount);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_notifications) {
        // TODO: display unread notifications.
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void update() {
    if (count>=5)
    {count = count +1;}
    display(count);
}

private void display(int count) {
    notif = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.badge_notification_1);
    notif.setText(""+ count);
}}
```

In the Adapter class, I added these line in the Onclick method :

```
if(c instanceof RankActivity){
  ((RankActivity)c).update();
                    }
```

I've learned from other posts that casting a class here was to avoid because it might lead to runtime exceptions, but it worked for me.

**This is the new Adapter class :**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

Context c;
ArrayList<criteria> critere;

public RecyclerAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<criteria> critere) {
    this.c = c;
    this.critere = critere;

}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView criteria, plus, update;
    ImageButton btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4;
    Boolean click1, click2, click3, click4;
    ImageView image, crown;
    RelativeLayout layout;
    LinearLayout ranked;
    ImageView check;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    public ClipData.Item currentItem;
    public View view;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;

        btn1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn4);

        layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.check_view);
        ranked = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank_layout);
        check = itemView.findViewById(R.id.check_image);

        criteria = itemView.findViewById(R.id.criteria_text);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.criteria_pic);

        crown = itemView.findViewById(R.id.crown_rank);
        plus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.plus);

    }

}

@Override
public RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.recycler_model,parent,false);

    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final criteria crit = critere.get(position);

    final String name = crit.getName();
    holder.criteria.setText(name);
    holder.layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.crown.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.plus.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    PicassoClient.downloadImage(c,crit.getImageurl(),holder.image);

    holder.btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(c);
                View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_rank, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);

                dialog.setView(dialogView);
                dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.btn_press_rank1);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setTitle(R.string.crit1);
                dialog.setMessage("The " + name + " was very unsatisfiying");
                final EditText userInput = (EditText) dialogView
                        .findViewById(R.id.comment_field);

                dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //checked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.check.bringToFront();
                        holder.ranked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.crown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.plus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        if(c instanceof RankActivity){
                            ((RankActivity)c).update();
                        }
                    }
                })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.annuler, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                //checked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                holder.layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                holder.ranked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder.crown.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                holder.plus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });

                final AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
                alert.show();

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return critere.size();
}}
```

For the badge :

**Menu_user layout**
In the menu folder :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.journaldev.collapsingtoolbarlayout.ScrollingActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Rank"
    android:onClick="OnSave"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
    <!--android:icon="@drawable/ic_ok"-->

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_notifications"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:icon="@drawable/main_menu_notification"
    android:title="Notifications"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

**Notification_update layout**
In the layout folder :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:clickable="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/badge_layout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout_item_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:background="@drawable/crown1" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/badge_notification_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/relative_layout_item_count"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_notification_overlay"
        android:text="5"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it will help someone else.

Comment: better to use **`interface`**

Comment: @Ratilal Chopda, Can you explain why please ?

Comment: because  if you call the public methods of your Activity directly from the Adapter class, you will not be able to re-use your Activity in other Activities without implementing hacky solutions (like **`if(c instanceof RankActivity){
  ((RankActivity)c).update();
                    }`** ),

Comment: rest is your choice @Mary

Comment: It’s my pleasure, Welcome dear

Answer (score 1):

follow this steps

1.create one **`interface`** like this

```
public interface Counter
{
    public void setCounter(int count);
}
```

2.than add this code in your Activity

```
private Counter counter;
counter = new Counter() {
            @Override
            public void setCounter(int count) {
                Log.e("Ser_Counter", "" + count);
                tvCountFav.setText(count + "");
                Toast.makeText(SearchResultClass.this, "Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
```

3.pass this **`interface`** as paramter to your adapter class like this

```
YourAdapteradapter = new YourAdapter(SearchResultClass.this, ArrayList, counter);
```

4.add **`counter`** code in your adapter class constructor

```
 private Counter counter;
 public SearchResultAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FilterDataModel> filterDataModelArrayList, Counter counter) {
        this.context = context;
        this.filterDataModelArrayList = filterDataModelArrayList;
        this.counter = counter;
    }
```

5.fire counter inteface method in side click listener like this

```
holder.addLikeImagevView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter.setCounter(1);
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've followed your steps, but i get a NullPointerException in my adapter Class, on counter.setcounter

Comment: @user3805411 did you decare **`private Counter counter;`** in adapter class also

Comment: yes I declared *private Counter counter;* in my adapter class

Comment: can you share your NullPointerException whole error

Comment: 'PID: 4854
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void xx.M_UI.Counter.setCounter(int)' on a null object reference at xx.M_UI.RecyclerAdapter$1$2.onClick(RecyclerAdapter.java:126) at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:163) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)'

Comment: @user3805411 can please update your question where you add this steps so i can find mistake

Comment: I've updated my question with your proposition, please check my update

Comment: @user3805411  where is **`interface Counter`**

Comment: @user3805411 where do you implement step 1

Comment: I've created an Interface 'public interface Counter {
    public void setCounter(int count);
}'

Comment: @user3805411 test case unistall your app than install again

Comment: send me a mail i will sent you a demo code for that @user3805411